# How to check if a row header is clicked in a datagridview when using CellClicked event in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridrowheader

I have a datagridview where I pop up a dateTimeSelector on the clicked cell using the `dataGridView1_CellClick` event. However, if I click on one of the row headers it gives the following error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index'

Here is the code I use for reference:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("SalesNr") != 0 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("PName") != 0  &&
                 dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("Type") != 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                cellRect = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
                dateTimePicker1.Size = new Size(cellRect.Width, cellRect.Height);
                dateTimePicker1.Location = new Point(cellRect.X, cellRect.Y);
                dateTimePicker1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

I would like to have a solution to check whether the clicked cell was a row header. If it is, then I simply will not pop up the dateTimeSelector. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Eda

Comment: Did you set e.RowIndex != -1 ?

Comment: @ggeorge yes I did, it prevents the clicks on the column header but not on the row header

Comment: Show the actual code! - All you probably need to do is to test for ColumnIndex to be -1.

Comment: We can't help you unless see what you did.

Comment: @Akif added the code.

Comment: @TaW I tried `ColumnIndex = -1` but it does not work.

Comment: Ah now the code shows and it is clearly as we all told you: Since ColumnIndex is -1 for the RowHeaders you can't use it to access a column which start from #0!

Comment: Yes I just saw that, sorry. All other comments still apply. What exactly do you want to happen when the user clicks a rowheader? Nothing? Then simply put `if (e.ColumnIndex == -1) return; ` at the start of th event!

Comment: @TaW There is no such thing as `e.ColumnHeader`, it is underlined with red line.

Comment: Yup, a typo; corrected.

Comment: @TaW it worked, thanks!